# PHP/MySQL multi-table join/union

Tags: mysql

I'm new to MySQL and am having troubles selecting items from multiple tables.

I have 3 tables (users, groups, group_members). Here is what each table has:

- users: user_id, user_email, user_name
- groups: group_id, group_name
- group_members: group_id, user_id

Given user_id I want to find `user_email`, `user_name`, `group_id` and `group_name` in one query. The problem is that the user can be in 3 groups at a time so somehow in my query I need to grab three rows from the group_members and groups tables. Any help would be greatly appreciated, below are my two best attempts.

```
SELECT groups.group_id, groups.group_name, users.user_email, users.user_name 
     FROM groups, membership, users
     WHERE membership.user_id=<user id> AND 
           membership.group_id = groups.group_id LIMIT 3;

SELECT groups.group_id, groups.group_name, users.user_email, users.user_name 
     FROM groups 
         LEFT JOIN membership ON groups.group_id = membership.group_id 
         LEFT JOIN users ON membership.user_id = users.user_id 
     WHERE (users.user_id = <user id>);
```

I was able to get one row of the group_id and group_name but not all 3. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
    SELECT groups.group_id, groups.group_name, users.user_email, users.user_name 
    FROM groups, membership, users 
    WHERE users.user_id=%s AND
          membership.user_id=users.user_id AND 
          membership.group_id = groups.group_id 
    LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT groups.group_id, groups.group_name, users.user_email, users.user_name 
FROM users 
     left inner join membership on membership.user_id = users.user_id
     inner join groups.group_id on groups.group_id = membership.group_id
Where users.user_id = %user_id%
```

Problem here, that you will get as many rows with duplicate email and username, as many groups user belongs to. If you want username and email only once, and a list of groups, then it will be 2 requests.

But this will also return you username and email with nulls in group_id and group_name in case, when user does not belong to any groups.

Comment: If it is only for display, you could consider <code>select ..., group_concat( groups.group_name) from ... group by users.user_id</code>